# Вывод элементов массива на консоль

Tags: java

Дана задача. Есть массив чисел `{5, 8, 1, 31, 17, 16, 2, 6, 5, 13}`
Мне нужно вывести на экран таким образом:

```
5, 13
8, 5
1, 6
31, 2
17, 16
```

Вывести первую строчку получилось, но как дальше хз. Алгоритм понимаю.

```
int [] a = {5, 8, 1, 31, 17, 16, 2, 6, 5, 13};

for (int i = 0; i <= a.length - 1; i = i + a.length - 1) {
    System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
}
```

Comment: каким "таким" образом?

Comment: @Эникейщик вон тем ↑  %)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский тогда System.out.println("5, 13\n8, 5\n1, 6\n31, 2\n17, 16");

Answer (score 2):

Это можно реализовать множеством способов, но, имхо, наиболее простой для понимания способ это проставить два указателя: на начало и конец массива и с каждой итерацией двигать их навстречу друг другу:

```
int [] a = {5, 8, 1, 31, 17, 16, 2, 6, 5, 13};
int left = 0;
int right = a.length-1;
while(left<right) {
    System.out.println(a[left] + " "+a[right]);
    left++;
    right--;
}
//Строка ниже нужна если средний элемент массива с нечетным 
//количеством элементов нужно выводить только один раз.
//Если его нужно продублировать, то строку нужно удалить,
//а в цикле изменить условие на left<=right
if(left==right) System.out.println(a[left]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Цикл можно организовать до середины массива. Дальше не имеет смысла, т.к. мы выводим числа попарно начиная от конца до середины.

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length / 2; ++i) {
    System.out.println(a[i] + ", " + a[a.length - 1 - i]);
}                                     ^----------------^
                                  Берём число с конца зеркально
```

Но тут многое не учитывается. Например, что в массиве может быть нечётное количество чисел

---

```
int middle = (int)Math.floor((a.length - 1) / 2);
    
for (int i = 0; i <= middle; ++i) {
    if (i == middle && a.length % 2 != 0)
        System.out.println(a[i]);
    else
        System.out.println(a[i] + " " + a[a.length - 1 - i]);
}
```

Comment: а не лучше ли будет после цикла (из 1го кода) проверить длину массива на четность и вывести или не вывести центральный элемент ?

Comment: Да, можно......

Comment: Можно просто `int middle = (a.length - 1) / 2;`